# playing HTML5 Audio on Android Chrome

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am trying to play an audio file (MP3 in this case) with an HTML Audio tag on a Chrome browser running on Android. The same page used on a desktop Chrome works perfectly. The play action is triggered from a user click event (noticed other questions about this).

Here is the HTML for the audio player

```
<audio id="callAudio" controls></audio>
```

There is a button on the page (I'm using AngularJS)

```
<a class="button" ng-click="playerPlay()"><i class="icon ion-play"></i> Play</a>
```

The controller has

```
function getPlayer() {
  return document.getElementById('callAudio');
}
$scope.playerPlay = function() {
  getPlayer().play();
};
```

Looking at the Chrome develper tools, network tab I can see on the desktop client
[image]
with the details
[image]

On the other hand on the Android chrome I get
[image]
With the details
[image]

Why is the text red on the Android side, even though the status code is 200?
What is the `partial content`?

**UPDATE** 
Another data point: I have a HTML5 Audio tag pointing to a random web MP3 file and it is playing just fine (on Chrome+Android). But when I point it to the same MP3 stored locally it won't play. I cross tested the same on Android on Win7 and it works fine there.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I also have the same problem and I see in the console "200 OK" in red.

Comment: I am getting having this same issue.  It looks like it is because the request doesn't send back any data and I am expecting something(using angular the success callback expects data).  Honestly I don't know but that is my assumption.  Is you request actually returning data?